# Creating a SerDes for Windowed Data on Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, aggregation, apache-kafka-streams, serialization

I'm having some trouble to create a SerDes to use with data I'm aggregating, and need to send to another topic, via '.to()', however, I need to create a SerDes for windowed data, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

We can create the Serilizer and DeSerilizer for windowed data in the following ways.

```
StringSerializer stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();
StringDeserializer stringDeserializer = new StringDeserializer();
Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(stringSerializer,stringDeserializer);

WindowedSerializer<String> windowedSerializer = new WindowedSerializer<>(stringSerializer);
WindowedDeserializer<String> windowedDeserializer = new WindowedDeserializer<>(stringDeserializer);
Serde<Windowed<String>> windowedSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(windowedSerializer,windowedDeserializer);
```

Use of Serilizer/DeSerilizer in the windowed data is given below.

```
KStream<String,StockTransaction> transactionKStream =  kStreamBuilder.stream(stringSerde,transactionSerde,"stocks");

transactionKStream.map((k,v)-> new KeyValue<>(v.getSymbol(),v))
                              .through(stringSerde, transactionSerde,"stocks-out")
                              .groupBy((k,v) -> k, stringSerde, transactionSerde)
                              .aggregate(StockTransactionCollector::new,
                                   (k, v, stockTransactionCollector) -> stockTransactionCollector.add(v),
                                   TimeWindows.of(10000),
                                   collectorSerde, "stock-summaries")
                    .to(windowedSerde,collectorSerde,"transaction-summary");
```

I would suggest you to go through the following content to get more information.

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.WindowedSerializer

Comment: According to https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/package-summary.html , there is no class named "Windowed(De)Serializer", I assume, since I want to use tumbling windows, I'll have to use the TimeWindowedSerializer?

Comment: WindowedDeserializer is custom Deserializer, you can found this at https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/master/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/WindowedDeserializer.java. Yes, you have to use TimeWindowedSerializer

Comment: @RohitYadav I would suggest that you update your answer to use` TimeWindowedSerde`...

Comment: This way the types seem to agree:

 WindowedSerializer<String> windowedSerializer = new TimeWindowedSerializer<String>(new StringSerializer());
 Deserializer<Windowed<String>> windowedDeserializer = new TimeWindowedDeserializer<String>(new StringDeserializer());
 Serde<Windowed<String>> windowedSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(windowedSerializer, windowedDeserializer);